# Selecting all Permutations Without Repetition using Regular Expressions in Python

Tags: python, regex, combinatorics

I have three classes of characters, say letters `[A-Za-z]`, numbers `[0-9]`, and symbols `[!@#$]`. The particular symbols don't really matter for the sake of the argument. I would like to use a regular expression in Python so that I can select all permutations on these three classes with a length of three, without repetition.

For example, the following would successfully match:

```
a1!
4B_
*x7
```

And the following would fail:

```
ab!
BBB
*x_
a1!B
```

How would I go about this without explicitly writing out each potential permutation of classes in my regular expression?

I have previously attempted the following solution:

```
import re
regex = r"""
              ([A-Za-z]|[0-9]|[!@#$])
    (?!\1)    ([A-Za-z]|[0-9]|[!@#$])
    (?![\1\2])([A-Za-z]|[0-9]|[!@#$])
    """
s = "ab1"
re.fullmatch(regex, s, re.VERBOSE)
```

However the string `ab1` is improperly matched. This is because the group references `\1` and `\2` refer to the actual matched *contents* of the groups, and not to the *regular expressions* contained within the groups.

Then, how do I refer to the regular expressions contained within prior matched groups, and not to their actual contents?

Comment: Why would `*xf` match?

Comment: Oops! Sorry, it would not. I will fix it. Thank you for noticing

Comment: The post has been edited to satisfy the requirements of a valid Stack Overflow question

Comment: If `4B_` must pass, you probably want to also allow `_`, not just `[!@#$]`. Also, `[^\1]` matches in fact any char other than the `\x01` char, not any char other than what Group 1 holds. Inside character classes, backreferences no longer are treated as such. You can't use backreferences to negate pattern part. `ab1` is matched becauie `b` is not equal to `a` and `1` is not equal to `a` and `1`.

Comment: Well, if  `*x_` should not pass, `4B_` should not pass either. If `*x7` must pass, then you also need to support `*`. You need to use something very similar to https://ideone.com/QdT85N, `rx = re.compile(r"""(?a)(?!(?:[\W\d_]*[^\W\d_]){2})(?!(?:\D*\d){2})(?!(?:[^!@\#$]*[!@\#$]){2})[\w!@\#$]{3}""")` (see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Hfcwoq/1))

Comment: One of the requirements to be a valid question is being _practical_ in nature. Artificial tool selection constraints that one wouldn't use in any real-world program are potentially disqualifying.

Comment: Charles Duffy, thank you for letting me know that regular expressions in Python would be artificial and impractical to solve this problem. I may edit the question to allow for answers with less stringent requirements. I currently am working on a Python project largely centered around the use of regular expressions. It is for this reason that I chose to ask if the above features are possible to implement in Python's regex.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that you can't use backreferences to negate a part of a pattern, you may only use them to match/negate *the same values as captured in the corresponding capturing group*.

Note `[^\1]` matches any char other than the `\x01` char, not any char other than what Group 1 holds, because, inside character classes, backreferences are no longer reated as such.
`ab1` is matched becauie `b` is not equal to `a` and `1` is not equal to `a` and `1`.

What you can use is a sequence of negative lookaheads that would "exclude" matching under certain conditions, like the string cannot have two digits/letters/special chars.

```
rx = re.compile(r"""
  (?!(?:[\W\d_]*[^\W\d_]){2})      # no two letters allowed
  (?!(?:\D*\d){2})                 # no two digits allowed
  (?!(?:[^_!@\#$*]*[_!@\#$*]){2})  # no two special chars allowed
  [\w!@\#$*]{3}                    # three allowed chars
""", re.ASCII | re.VERBOSE)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5rQ5cu/1). The negated character classes are replaced with `.*` in the demo since the test is performed against a single multiline text and not separate strings.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/2kQDzR):

```
import re
passes = ['a1!','4B_','*x7']
fails = ['ab!','BBB','*x_','a1!B']
rx = re.compile(r"""
  (?!(?:[\W\d_]*[^\W\d_]){2})      # no two letters allowed
  (?!(?:\D*\d){2})                 # no two digits allowed
  (?!(?:[^_!@\#$*]*[_!@\#$*]){2})  # no two special chars allowed
  [\w!@\#$*]{3}                    # three allowed chars
""", re.ASCII | re.VERBOSE)
for s in passes:
    print(s, ' should pass, result:', bool(rx.fullmatch(s)))
for s in fails:
    print(s, ' should fail, reuslt:', bool(rx.fullmatch(s)))
```

Output:

```
a1!  should pass, result: True
4B_  should pass, result: True
*x7  should pass, result: True
ab!  should fail, reuslt: False
BBB  should fail, reuslt: False
*x_  should fail, reuslt: False
a1!B  should fail, reuslt: False
```

Answer (score -1):

A straightforward solution is to not write out the permutations yourself, but to let Python do it with the help of [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations).

```
from itertools import permutations

patterns = [
    '[a-zA-Z]',
    '[0-9]',
    '[!@#$]'
]

regex = '|'.join(
    ''.join(p)
    for p in permutations(patterns)
)
```